# One half of my mobile home electrical won't work

Tags: electrical-distribution

I was switching out a couple of switches when I bumped two of the wires, they sparked and popped. Now on one whole side of the mobile home the outlets and switches won't work.

I checked the breakers and they're all good. So I unwired everything I did, but it still wont work.

Is it a broken breaker or what?

Comment: You need an elevtrician on site. You may have fried a wire, you may have done other kinds of damage; the only way to know is to find all the points of damage (there maybe more than one) and fix them. Lesson: __never__ work on hot circuits until you are much, much, much more experienced -- and even then, doing so is almost always stupid unless there is a very specific reason to do so.

Comment: I think you could have ended at "never work on hot circuits", which is something a DIY'er should never do, no exception. Anyone with a real need (and training) to work on a hot circuit won't be coming here to look for advice.

Comment: True enough, @johnny, but in my experience that leads to "but I saw the pro do it" which brings us back to the qualifications... they probably shouldn't have either, and they know when and how they can minimize the risk.

Comment: House fires are no fun, especially if you die in them.This really is time to hire a pro.

Answer (score 1):

Many times when breakers trip they are hard to visually see since the handle may not move much. Make sure you shut all the breakers all the way off and then turn them back on. Don't forget the main.

You may have blown a fuse in the main disconnect seeing the mobile home and now you are only getting have the transformer or one leg of it. That would be the thing to check after resetting all the breakers.

Comment: i did  reset all the breakers i even used a test light t check them . so should i replace the main breaker? if im only getting half a leg?

Comment: @user48467 Half a leg? Are you only getting one?

Comment: If there is power coming into the main breaker on both legs of the service then your main breaker is apparently the problem. But I am saying there may be a fused disconnect ahead of your main breaker. You could have blown one of the fuses in that disconnect and that would shut down half the power in the home when all the breakers appear normal.